# Bootstrap responsive menu - How to change height for larger viewports

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, navigation

thanks for taking the time to read this and possibly help me out. I'm new to responsive layouts and this is my first attempt at customising a Bootstrap template I'm using from StartBootstrap http://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/modern-business/.

Here's the page I'm working on:
http://www.designbyantony.com/JMP%20Bootstrap/contentpage.html

I'm having trouble increasing the height of the menu bar which should look like this artwork screenshot - ie: half the logo is currently missing. It does appear when the menu collapses and the toggle is activated but even there, there's overlap and it looks messy - but at least it's in the correct position above the menu items. I reckon the menu bar probably needs to be around 100px high when viewed on desktops and drop to around 70px (with the logo shrinking to fit it) at mobile sizes.

My apologies in advance for not using SASS or LESS but I'm trying to do one thing at a time initially by using my own custom.css file to overwrite bootstrap.css components as I need to.

Really hoping someone can help a complete novice with this.

Antony
UK

Comment: Here's the screenshot of how I'd like it to look http://www.designbyantony.com/JMP%20Bootstrap/images/JM%20Web2.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two main areas you're going to have to tackle here.

The first one is the `min-height` property for the `.navbar` class. Currently it is set to `50px`. Bump this up to `115px` or whatever works for you. This setting used when the page is smaller and the navigation collapses. You'll notice adjusting this doesn't center your navigation elements vertically. Which brings us to the second area you need to adjust.

```css
.navbar {
     min-height: 115px;
}
```

The second area is the padding on the anchor elements `<a>` in your `ul`s with the class of `.navbar-nav`. They are targeted with this selector `.navbar-nav > li > a`. This selector is in two places, one of which is inside a media query. The one in the media query is the one you want to adjust. Adjust the `padding-top` and `padding-bottom` values to something like `45px`.

```css
@media (min-width: 768px) {
     .navbar-nav {
          padding-top: 45px;
          padding-bottom: 45px;
      } 
}
```

I belive that Twitter Bootstrap has made sure that the total height of the anchor elements, line-height plus padding is the same height as the min-height value in `.navbar`. So you might want to do the same.

Comment: Thank you hungerstar - I'll try this and report back. Antony

Comment: Hi hungerstar - I tried this and it worked perfectly - thank you so much. I wondered if I could ask how I might sort out an issue with the menu items overlapping the logo between 768 and 992 viewport sizes - I wonder if I shoudl just ensure that the menu toggle appears at 992 rather than waiting for the veiwport to go down to 768? Um - not sure how I might do this to be honest.

Comment: Think I've managed to get this to work: 

@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {
    .navbar-collapse.collapse {
        display: none !important;
    }
    .navbar-collapse.collapse.in {
        display: block !important;
    }
    .navbar-header .collapse, .navbar-toggle {
        display:block !important;
    }
    .navbar-header {
        float:none;
    }
}

Comment: One option is to show the menu toggle sooner than later and another option would be to adjust the padding, font-size etc. of the anchor elements in the `.navbar-nav` ULs. I also noticed that your logo is not quite centered, the reason for this is that your negative margin of `-80px` only account for the size of the image an not the padding of the `.navbar-brand` element. Which is `-15px`.

Comment: Hi hungerstar - thanks for the heads up on the centering - think I've fixed it. I think I may need to adjust the .navbar-nav ULs as you suggest as there's an issue at just below 992px where the nav collapses. When the toggle is clicked the menu shows below in a broken row. A task for tomorrow - thank you for all your help - I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.navbar {  
    min-height: 115px;
}
```

Your bootstrap css rule has a `min-width` property which we just increase.

You should create a new css file and link to it under your bootstrap and overwrite your style.

And you should really post your code of the part that has problems instead of linking images.

Comment: Thank you Antonio - I'll try this and report back.

Comment: Antonio - thanks for taking the time to read my question and answer it. Antony

Comment: No problem. If the answer has helped in any way or form be sure to give it a upwote

Comment: Antonio - I would but I'm afraid I can't with a rating of only 12 :-/